# How to check motherboard chipset?

Tags: virtualization, intel

I am trying to enable Intel VT-x on my Clevo W150ER. The processor is an Intel i7-3610QM and it supports Intel VT-x. However, I've read that my motherboard also has to support it, namely, the chipsets of the motherboard must support it. So I was wondering if anyone here knows a command that can tell me which chipsets my motherboard is using and if they support Intel VT-x as well.

Sources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429296/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x?noredirect=1#comment23563737_16429296
- http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2010/04/02/does-my-product-support-intel-vt

Comment: The easiest way to find out the chipset is to look at the detailed system specs from the manufacturer, it should say what the chipset is.

Comment: Flame_Phoenix the answer here depends on a hardware feature. I would actually try to use the answer provided and use the Search option. This is not really related to Ubuntu and more related to a BIOS feature. In my case, the DZ68DB and the DP35DP from intel have this feature. I would suggest, since your processor does have it, to find a motherboard that can also handle it.

Comment: I found 'cat /proc/cpuinfo' and 'lscpu' (remove '') to work best without needing apt-get

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That command you're looking for is `dmidecode`. `dmidecode` is a tool for dumping a computer's DMI (some say SMBIOS) table contents in a human-readable format.

To get a full infomation about system hardware:

```
dmidecode | less
```

You can use `dmidecode` with `grep` to get a specific section from command's results:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -A4 'Base Board Information'
```

You can use `dmidecode` with `--string` argument to display a specific piece of information:

```
sudo dmidecode --string baseboard-manufacturer
```

For the full list of supported strings checkout the man page.

```
man dmidecode
```

If `dmidecode` is not available on your system, you can install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install dmidecode
```